# Two Tabstrips with Two Kendo Grids

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

i want to load two kendogrid respective with two tabstrips. The requirement is when i click the tab then only grid should load. It should not load two grids when page loads

Comment: You could consider using one grid declaration which is created/destroyed and rebuilt using other data based on the tab item selected.

Comment: I would look into creating a partial view for both grids. Then when you select a tab, call the partial view you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish that similar to what Supersnake describes by calling an Action on my Controller that returns a partial view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Name("myTabStrip")
    .Items(tabs =>
    {
        tabs.Add().Text("Tab1").LoadContentFrom("Tab1Load", "MyController", new { id = Model.ID }).Selected(true);
        tabs.Add().Text("Tab2").LoadContentFrom("Tab2Load", "MyController", new { id = Model.ID });
    })
    .Events(e => e.Select("onTabSelect"))
```

)

My controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Tab1Load(int id)
{
    // load view model (vm) for partial 
    return PartialView("_Tab1Content", vm);
}
```

You could also just [load the partial directly](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajax). Word of caution: when the tabs are loaded via AJAX it can affect jquery issues like validation. Grids should be fine though.